# How to declare/use Arrays and Quantifiers in Z3Py?

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm new to Z3py and I found an exercise where it would ask to check if some verification conditions were true. Up to this moment, the exercises I've done were basically to transform simple propositional formulas into z3py clauses, something like:

```
Propositional Formula would be:

(n>=4) -> (x = y +2)

Which would become in Z3Py:

n, x, y = Ints('n x y')

s.add(Implies(n>=5, x == y+3))
```

The conditions I'm presented now, introduce Arrays and Quantifiers and after spending hours trying to figure it out on the documentation around, I'm still not able to get it properly done.

For example, how would I do the same process above but with the following conditions:

```
n ≥ 1 ∧ i = 1 ∧ m = A[0]
i <= n ∧ ∀j. 0 ≤ j < i → m ≥ A[j]
```

A little snippet of what I think that is correctly done:

```
i, n = Ints('i n')

s.add(And(n>=1, i == 1, ???)
s.add(And(i<=n,Implies(???))
```

How should I replace the ??? so that the conditions would be correctly transformed into Z3Py?

Solution:

```
- The constraint

n ≥ 1 ∧ i = 1 ∧ m = A[0]

would become in Z3Py:

A = Array('A', IntSort(), IntSort()) //Array declaration
i, n, m, j = Ints('i n m j') //Ints declaration for both constraints

And(n>=1, i==1, m==A[0])

- The constraint

i <= n ∧ ∀j. 0 ≤ j < i → m ≥ A[j]

would become:

And(i<=n,ForAll(j,Implies(And(j>=0,j<i),m>=A[j])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is quite ambiguous. Note that you've the constraints:

```
n ≥ 1 ∧ i = 1
```

and then

```
i <= n
```

but that consequent is already implied by the first, and hence is redundant. Meaning, if you add them both to the solver like you did with your `s.add` lines, then it won't really mean much of anything at all.

I'm guessing these two lines actually arise in different "subparts" of the problem, i.e., they aren't used together for the same verification goal. And, making an educated guess, you're trying to say something about the maximum element of an array; where `i` is some sort of a loop-counter. The first line is what happens before the loop starts, and the second is the invariant the loop-body ensures. If this is the case, you should be explicit about that.

Assuming this is the case, then these sorts of problems are usually modeled on the "body" of that loop, i.e., you need to show us exactly what sort of a "program" you're dealing with. That is, these constraints will only make sense in the presence of some sort of a transformation of your program variables.

Comment: You're right, the constraints I've presented are only a part of a bigger problem. What I was looking for was simply for examples on how to work with arrays and quantifiers for something like the constraints I've presented. Would you be able to create some examples with maybe more simple constraints, that would have either Arrays or Quantifiers like ForAll? A single example of each would allow me to understand how to apply it to my exercises. I'm not interested in the solution of the constraints at all.

Comment: Stack-overflow works the best if you show what you tried, and where you get stuck; i.e., actual pieces of code. You might want to start reading through this page: https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/advanced-examples.htm It talks about both arrays and quantifiers. Once you review it, try to formulate your constraints based on an example and ask again. Asking specific questions about concrete pieces of code is much more effective than asking for open-ended questions on this forum.

Comment: I'm sorry but more specific than the question I asked, is a bit hard. I'll post the solution since I found how to do it already.